# What are the requirements of std::map's compare parameter regarding strict ordering?

Tags: c++, dictionary, comparison

I have an integral type, which represents a ring buffer index. The less comparison function defined this way:

```
friend bool operator < (const CircularValue & lhs, const CircularValue &rhs) {
    UInt max = lhs.value + std::numeric_limits<UInt>::max() / 2;
    return (lhs.value < max)
        ? rhs.value > lhs.value && rhs.value < max
        : rhs.value > lhs.value || rhs.value < max;
}
```

Lhs considered lower than rhs if rhs takes place in the half of the available interval above lhs. 
I would like to use it in a map as key, but not sure if it can cause problem. It has the property of irreflexivity and asymmetry, but not transitivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will cause problems. As described by [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare), the following requirements must be met by a comparator:

- `cmp(a,a)` yields `false`
- if `cmp(a,b)` yields true, then `cmp(b,a)` yields `false`
- if `cmp(a,b)`==`true` and `cmp(b,c)`==`true` then `cmp(a,c)` must also be `true` (this won't be met by your comparator)
- if `a` and `b` are to compare equal, then both `cmp(a,b)` and `cmp(b,a)` yield `false`